# Local topological properties

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology, terminology

Could we define the terms locally connected/compact/contractible/simply-connected/whatever to mean that there is a basis (for the topology on our space) of connected/compact/contractible/simply-connected/whatever subsets? I mean does this usage of these terms agree with the "standard" ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this doesn't always work. For instance, $\mathbb R$ is a locally compact space, but it has no basis composed of compact sets simply because the only compact and open set in $\mathbb R$ is the empty set.

Comment: I see. But what about the other properties. Do you know some way of unifying these "local properties", as I attempted above?

Comment: quite often your attempt will work, but you have to be careful. The example above shows you can't quite unify locality for all properties, so a single unified approach is hopeless. Having said that, it's typically quite easy to establish for any given local property if it's equivalent to having a basis with that property.

Comment: What if you replace "basis of open subsets" by "neighbourhood basis of each point"? Is there any counterexample?

Comment: To the contrary: I helps if we consider local connectivity: Then the weak and the strong conditions for local connectivity of X agree.